# Bold chapters and sections and normalsize subsections Table of Contents in KOMA-script

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script

I would like to make `chapter` and `section` appear bold in the `Table of Contents` (TOC). I am using a  `KOMA`-Script prototype. My Table of Contents looks like:

[image]

Although I define sections to be written in bold, they do not appear bold in the Table of Contens. Furthermore, chapters appear in a different font. Do you know why?

I include the table of content by this:

```
\begingroup
\changefont{phv}{m}{n}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

The class file looks like this:

```
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{14}\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontfamily{phv}\normalsize\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontfamily{phv}\normalsize\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontfamily{phv}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontfamily{phv}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontfamily{phv}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontfamily{phv}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
 \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
 \interlinepenalty\@M
 \leavevmode
 \@tempdima #3\relax
 \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
 {#4}\nobreak
 \leaders\hbox{\rmfamily\mdseries$\m@th
    \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
    mu$}\hfill
 \nobreak
 \hskip-.2em
 \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
 \par}%
 \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
\if@tocleft
  \ifx\toc@l@number\@empty\else
    \setlength\@tempdima{0\toc@l@number}%
  \fi
\fi

\begingroup
  \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \leavevmode \sectfont
  \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
  \hskip -\leftskip
  \@dottedtocline{0}{\z@}{1.3em}{\textbf{#1}}{{\changefont{phv}{m}{u}#2}}
  \penalty\@highpenalty
\endgroup
\fi
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It is better to post a MWE instead of the class file, which is presumably `scrbook`?

Comment: At a second look it does not seem to be a `class` file, but some userdefined style file. If I use the standard `scrbook` class,, sections are not printed bold in the `toc`.

Comment: I would remove or comment the `begingroup \changefont... \endgroup` statements.

Answer (score 2):

This is not meant as a solution or a real answer, it is posted to show the difference (So no need of voting for it ;-))

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% Other stuff    
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Einleitung}
% Text to come...
\chapter{Begriffe}

\section{Definitionen von Einkommen}
% Now with *bold* toc - entry!!! %
\section[\textbf{Definitionen von Einkommensrisiko}]{Definitionen von Einkommensrisiko}


\end{document}
```

I omitted the subsections due to lack of time.

It looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The KOMA-script manual describes the whole interface in the toc-subsection. Well, what about writing something like `\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\bfseries}`? And forget about the rest...